# How is the web.config handled by the ConfigurationManager from .NET?

Tags: iis, web-config, configurationmanager

On a project I am working on, we usually keep our application settings defined in a separate file.  This is how it has been done for many years, and going forward we would like to keep all system configurations in one file.  I was considering to use the web.config  section so I can just load the configurations that I need from my C# code running on the server using the ConfigurationManager class.

If I use our own way for the application settings, I would load it in a session and have it available for the application by loading values from the session.  After some reading online it looks like some of the performance issues behind using the session is that we have to deserialize the values from the session object.

Does IIS deserialize the web.config values each time we read values using the ConfigurationManager?

Thank you,
Vijay Selvaraj

Answer (score 1):

Web.config is read once upon loading of the AppDomain. It is refreshed if any changes are made to it or any referenced files (you can put sections into external files by using the configsection= attribute on a section)

Answer (score 1):

No, configuration sections are deserialized into the custom classes that reflect them only when the configuration file is re-read (such as when the app pool is recycled, a change to web.config is detected, and a couple of other conditions).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670633/when-is-web-config-read).