# Are the appSettings cached by the .NET framework or are they read from the file everytime you access them?

Tags: .net

I am looking inside the code inside `System.Configuration.dll` and it looks like the .NET framework reads the file every time you access `ConfigurationManager.Whatever`, for e.g. `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["foo"]`;

This worries me. This can't be. Please prove that I am wrong.

Comment: You can do a simple test yourself. Show a value from the config file. Edit the config file while the program is still running. Show the value again - it is the same. Also, you can use Process Monitor from Sysinternals to show file accesses - the config file is only accessed when the program starts.

Comment: Thank you. That's right.

Comment: @AndrewMorton You could put that down as an aswer if you want. It will help others also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a simple test yourself. Show a value from the config file. Edit the config file while the program is still running. Show the value again - it is the same.

Also, you can use [Process Monitor from Sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to show file accesses - the config file is only accessed when the program starts.

(It is different for web.config in ASP.NET applications, where a change in web.config results in the application being restarted: [When is the web.config file “executed”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11233540/1115360).)